Big query table partitioning based on time
I’m new to big query and was working on creating python function that fetches table partitioning of a table .
If bqtable.time_partioning:
   Print(table.time_partioning.field)
Elif bqtable.partioning-type==‘DAY’:
   Print(‘ingestion time’)

I’m confused about whether these two if statements are exclusive. Would the first condition be true if the table is partitioned by ingestion time?

Why are you doing that (what the global picture)? And how did you get the bq.table object? Can you share more of your code?

Not exclusive, need to go one layer deeper. If a table has partitioning (named, or pseudo-column _PARTITIONTIME), it would return True. However, if it is the latter, where no field name was specified, your return on the first conditional would be True --> None. The only time the elif would be run is if the table has no partitioning, and because of that, there would be no partitioning-type. If you're trying to determine if there is a partition and tell me if it's ingestion based or not you would do as below. Refer to Documentation
# Check if table has partitioning
if bqtable.time_partioning:
   if table.time_partioning.field: #Has partitioning, was the partitioning named with a field
      print(f"Table partioned by field: {table.time_partitioning.field}")
   else:
      print("Table partioned by (_PARTITIONTIME)") #Has partitioning but not named with a field

